# Saving a PyTorch models state_dict into redis cache

Tags: python, azure, redis, pytorch, distributed-computing

I’m building a distributed parameter/server type architecture and wanting to communicate model updates through table solutions on Azure.

I’m having a hard time finding any useful information about saving a PyTorch models state_dict into a redis cache. I’ve given up on Azure Cosmos tables because of the size limit (64kb) per entity and looked toward redis since model state_dict params/weights are much larger, even for a small model.

Does anyone have any recommendations for me on how to pursue this? Or if this is even possible?

Comment: Did you check RedisAI?

Comment: @GuyKorland I didn't realize redis had it available. I actually switched to this and used tensorset over name, param.data in model.named_parameters() to get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

My solution (after @GuyKorland commented above) was RedisAI.

I implemented key-value mehanism for model data and communicated it that way between VMs.

```
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    redisai_client.tensorset(f'{name}',param.data.numpy().cpu().detach())
```